# 32-bit MASM program Initializing variables

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, masm

I am writing a 32-bit MASM program to do numerous arithmetic. I want to initialize variables in my program such as num , val , etc.. in the declaration only once and only the first time. How do I do numerous arithmetic operations without re-initializing the variables?

ex:

```
num = 122             ; Initialize in declaration
val = 9               ; Initialize in declaration
res = val + num
cout << "res = " << res;
```

----------------------------- **How do I continue to compute without re-initializing num and val???**

```
num = 42
val = 100
val = val - num
cout << "val = " << val;
```

so do this only once in program:

```
num dword 122
val dword 9
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"How do I do numerous arithmetic operations without re-initializing the variables"*? You don't have to re-initialize them to perform arithmetic on them.

Comment: Yes I am aware that I can still perform arithmetic on them but is there is way for to reset the values or num and val to these newly wanted values without performing arithmetic to do so? @JesusPlusPlus11

Comment: You can assign new values to variables any time. Re-assigning a value doesn't differ from "first time" assigning in any significant way. (At least not much -- one may have to write `myvar dw 12345;` and later `mov myvar, $54321` to re-assign)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I wanted to know... if there was a command line as such. @Aki Suihkonen 1

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was as simple as:

```
num dword 122                  ; Initialize num
val dword 9                    ; Initialize val
```

---

```
mov num, 42                    ; NOW num = 42 
mov val, 100                   ; NOW val = 100
```

Thanks for the comments and response!